# Error starting cloned VM in Vsphere Client

Tags: virtualization, vmware

I cloned a VM in Vsphere Client as described [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/9249/HOW-TO-Clone-or-Copy-a-virtual-machine-in-VMware-vSphere-Hypervisor-ESX-ESXi-4-x-or-ESXi-5-0.html). When I try to start it, it unexpectedly reboot over and over itself. I get this error in console:

```
Call "EnvironmentBrowser.QueryTargetCapabilities" for object "45-envmgr" on ESXi "192.168.100.172" failed.
```

Which also shows another status message saying:

```
The object has been deleted or not created completely.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this page](https://code.vmware.com/apis/217/vsan#/doc/vim.EnvironmentBrowser.html) which documents `EnvironmentBrowser` for clues of which setting to edit.

Possibly something has a **relative path that is now modified**, or a **resource that's fully used up** or no longer available (or no longer valid, but that makes little sense if it's the same VM host).